# In which situations should do I perform a Fisher test?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, fishers-exact-test

I have the species richness (number of species) of different habitats.

```
          Habitat    species richness        No species richness
             Cr             42                       54
             Ed             69                       27
             Oa             47                       49
             Wl             74                       22
```

I would like to know if I can establish differences using Fisher test and why I can not get the F-statistic (yates and pearson corrections) in R using the function fisher.test  and fisher.multcomp (to perform fisher multiple comparisons).

Moreover, I have seen that Fisher test is better than Chi-square test when the sample size is low, Does it right?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing a Fisher test for a Chi-square test.

The Fisher's exact test of independence is not based on the F distribution and hence does not return F statistics. It is the exact version of the also commonly used Chi-square test, which is based on the $\chi^2$ distribution and approximates the Fisher test. The Chi-square test does have a Yates's correction for continuity.

Comment: The Fisher exact test is not the exact version of the chi-squared test; it uses a different statistic. You could do an exact (conditional) version of a chi-squared test (by conditioning on both margins, as the Fisher test does) but using the chi-squared statistic (rather than the probability associated with a given table under the null as the Fisher test does) for a test statistic. This exact conditional version of the chi-squared test is actually implemented as an option in the chi-squared test function in R.